# VBA to paste value using Range.Copy method with Offset

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently using the following code to consolidate data from Multiple sheets with the same range using Range.Copy method using Offset.

I am trying to Paste only Values instead of formulas. But, I get the formulas also which is leading to Error "#REF!".
Can anyone please help me with the correct syntax?
I just started learning VBA coding.

```
    For Each ws In Sheets(Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
    ws.Activate
    bottomD = Range("BC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("BC3:BE" & bottomD).Copy Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next ws
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly assign values, not need to use copy/paste and no need to select/activate:

```
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
    With ws.Range("BE3", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "BC").End(xlUp))
        Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) _
           .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).value = .value
    End With
Next ws
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without activating each sheet, and using pastespecial to copy values only

```
Sub x()

Dim ws As Worksheet, bottomD As Long

For Each ws In Sheets(Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
    bottomD = ws.Range("BC" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("BC3:BE" & bottomD).Copy
    Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SJR, it worked. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need.

`.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the .PasteSpecial method:

```
Range("BC3:BE" & bottomD).Copy
Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).pastespecial xlPasteValues
```